# MacBook display has vertical black and white lines on startup

Tags: macbook-pro, display, error, startup

My MackBook, on startup, its showing the following:

[image]

They are just a bunch of vertical black and white lines, and it gets stuck there.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Can you provide your Macbook model & os version ?

Comment: Its 2006 Macbook

Comment: This is the link for the specs of my macbook http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook/specs/macbook_2.0_white.html

Answer (score 3):

It's definitely hardware.  It's either the display has gone bad or your GPU (logic board) has gone bad (most likely case)

The first thing I would do is hook it up to an external monitor.  If it's present there as well, then you know it's GPU/logic board related.   If it goes away, then run [Apple Hardware Test (AHT)](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201257) to get some details.  (Hold the D key while booting from a powered off state with the AC adapter connected)

Either way, you will need to take it in for service.